# Can't find this specific Choose Your Own Adventure book

Tags: story-identification, choose-your-own-adventure

The book was kinda large but paperback and old, maybe 30-40 years. I distinctly remember an arm wrestling contest you needed to secretly drink a potion for, and the complete ending had you return to a house of dwarves where you're rewarded with jewels and a crown.
Additional info, you had to keep track of your provisions too, it played more like a game than a book. I remember the front cover had a man with blonde hair walking down a road, but I cannot remember anything else. I hope beyond hope this rings any bells for anyone.

Answer (score 24):

This is *(The) [Forest of Doom](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/802016.Forest_of_Doom)*, one of the 'Fighting Fantasy' gamebook series.

The book prominently features an arm-wrestling contest and the cover has a blond man.

> Quin explains that he will wager some Dust of Levitation against an
> item or coins to the value of 10 Gold Pieces. As you sit down at the
> table opposite him, you deftly slip the Armband of Strength on to your
> arm. You put your elbow on to the table and lock hands with him. His
> grip is like an iron jaw and his dark slanted eyes look confident. His
> biceps bulge and he gives the signal for the contest to begin. You start to push his arm down and are amazed at your own strength.
> Sweat breaks out on his forehead and you can see the disbelief and
> pain on his face. You push harder and force his arm on to the table in
> defeat.

[image]

Comment: I think you're right and just pulled it from the shelf and the 400th chapter has in it: *Gillibran listens and
frowns at the news of Bigleg his faithful servant.
Then he opens a drawer in the base of the throne
and reaches into it, pulling out a small silverbox and
a golden winged helmet, and hands them to you.
The helmet is worth hundreds of Gold Pieces and
you proudly place it on your head. A great roar of
approval comes from the crowd. You open the silver
box and find dozens of jewels and gems*

Comment: Oh my goodness, I almost feel silly. I keep seeing this book everywhere but never bothered to check the contents because of how different my memory of it was. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Samuel please make sure to upvote and accept the solution (by clicking on the upwards triangle and the checkmark)